# VS 2015 c++ compile issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have a code snipped I've been using for a while to create dynamic arrays, and it suddenly stopped working.

This is meant to create a dynamic array without the use of vector in c++ console applications. even all my older programs that have worked fine in the past no longer compile while its included though.

```
int main()
{
    int n = 5;

    AllocateArray newArray(n);

    int *myArray = newArray.create();

    delete[] myArray;

    return 0;
}

class AllocateArray {
private:
    int *newArray;
    int size;
public:
    AllocateArray(int);
    int* create() { return (newArray = new int[size]); }
    ~AllocateArray() {
        delete newArray;
    }
};

AllocateArray::AllocateArray(int n)
{
    size = n;
}
```

with this in the header

```
int* allocateArray(int n);
```

This is my error log, can anyone help find whats happening?

```
Severity    Code    Description
Error       C2065   'AllocateArray': undeclared identifier
Error       C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'newArray'  
Error       C3861   'newArray': identifier not found
Error       C2065   'newArray': undeclared identifier   
Error       C2228   left of '.create' must have class/struct/union
```

Comment: C++ needs the symbols you use to be declared (and sometimes defined) *before* they are used.

Comment: And is there a specific reason you don't use `std::vector`? It's in the *standard* library, so it's everywhere and works the same no matter what. It's also well-optimized and debugged.

Comment: The only reason I'm not using vector is for learning exercises, I would definitely use vector for production apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your declaration of `AllocateArray` before `main()`.

As user @JoachimPileborg explains:

> C++ needs the symbols you use to be declared (and sometimes defined)
>   before they are used.

```
class AllocateArray {
private:
    int *newArray;
    int size;
public:
    AllocateArray(int);
    int* create() { return (newArray = new int[size]); }
    ~AllocateArray() {
        delete[] newArray; // changed to 'delete[]' from 'delete'
    }
};

int main()
{
    int n = 5;

    AllocateArray newArray(n);

    int *myArray = newArray.create();

    //delete[] myArray; // error: delete is called by AllocateArray's destructor.

    return 0;
}

AllocateArray::AllocateArray(int n)
{
    size = n;
}
```

**Warning**

You are deleting the same pointer **P** twice. Once in `AllocateArray`'s destructor and once in `main()`. **P** is returned by your `create()` function to `myArray` in `main()`. Then you delete it, but at the end of `main()`, `AllocateArray`'s destructor is called and it tries to delete **P** again.

**Notes**

You should check out the RAII idiom if you plan on allocating arrays by yourself. However, you should consider using `std::vector<T>` instead, as it manages memory for you (and provides a very useful range of functionalities).

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work, and I probably had it wrong all along. Not sure why it let me compile before. is the delete newArray not required in the destructor, and will it be successful with just the delete in main?

Comment: Note that the `delete` used in the destructor is also the wrong form. @JustinTennant, Rather than returning something that the user should delete, make it your class's responsibility to manage that.

Comment: You should instead remove the delete from main and keep the one in `AllocateArray`'s destructor, because that gets called even if there is an exception in between your allocation of the array and the time you actually call delete. @chris is absolutely correct, but it's probably an oversight, since you used the correct `delete` in `main()`.

Comment: Thanks so much both of you. Just starting C++ after a couple of years c#. I fixed the delete form in my destructor and removed it from main, all my programs now work fully as intended!